# Automatically increase size of UIViewController containing a UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, uistackview

I am trying to achieve a pretty complex view hierarchy. My idea is to build a UI similar to the AirPods and HomePod configurator sheet showing from the bottom part of the screen.

I have a fullscreen `UIViewController` which has a child view controller of type `UINavigationController`. In this navigation controller, I will push and manager all my view controllers.
Now I have a view controller which has a UIStackView with some content in it, and it's text has variable size. Currently, the `navigationController` has a fixed height constraint but obviously I want to change that height based on the size of the content of the visible view controller currently in the `navigationController` stack.

Here is a picture of what the view hierarchy currently looks like.
[image]

I tried different approaches like setting the compression resistance priority on the labels to 1000 to avoid them clipping but the container view has a fixed height, so they don't grow in any way. Basically, I need a way to figure the content of the `UIStackView` and then pass that height to the top most view controller which changes the height constant of the `UINavigationController`.

Did anyone implement a system to manage this kind of view hierarchy?

Comment: Do you have your `UINavigationController` embedded in a ContainerView?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to the problem:

```
let size = stackView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
let viewControllerSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: size.height + 40)
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "DidChangeContentSize"), object: viewControllerSize)
stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

40 is the spacing around the `UIStackView` in my case. The top most view controller observes the notification and changes the container view controller height constraint constant. Yes, you could delegates to pass up this information instead of `NotificationCenter`.